# Trouble with float addition using arange() from numpy

Tags: python, numpy, addition

I would like to test a set of 3 variables `w1,w2,w3`. When the sum of these is equal to 1, I want to print `"YATTA"`.

```
import numpy as np

for w1 in np.arange(0.10,0.45,0.05):
       for w2 in np.arange(0.10,0.45,0.05):
           for w3 in np.arange(0.10,0.45,0.05):
               sumw=w1+w2+w3
               if(sumw==1.0):
                   print "YATTA"
               else:
                   print w1,w2,w3,sumw
```

When I run this I observe something very weird! For example when my variables are :

```
w1 = 0.2
w2 = 0.4
w3 = 0.4
```

`sumw` is  1.0 **BUT** it's not printing `"YATTA"` and instead the `else` statement is executed.

Why does my code behave like this, and how would I solve this issue?

Comment: [Welcome to the world of floating point arithmetic.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: This must be a duplicate, similar questions get asked all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have fallen foul of the fact that floating point arithmetic isn't exact.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) for a good explanation why you are getting the results you are.

The *quick* explanation of your particular case is that, and your decimals cannot be converted exactly into binary so w1, w2 and w3 are not exactly what you think they are.  More generally: most real numbers cannot be represented in a finite number of digits, and most floating point operations must have rounding.

As a fix, instead of comparing floats for equality as you are doing now instead use the [`np.isclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) function instead

```
np.isclose(sumw, 1.0)
```